# floor and ceil from QCL (Quantum Computer Language)

Tags: operators, quantum-computing, qcl

I'm working on QCL and some questions came up about internal functions.
I'd like to know what the operators `floor(something)` and `ceil(something)` are.
I know they are related to math operations, but what do they do exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Floor removes the decimal point, ceil turns the decimal part into .9999 repeating if it's already there (which is the same as a whole number).

So floor(4.6) loses the .6, ceil(4.6) becomes 4.9999... or 5. Also, ceil(5.0) will return 5, as the decimal part is 0.